# Alternative to scipy maximum_filter to find peaks?

Tags: audio, dsp-core, scipy

I'm using scipy `maximum_filter` together with `binary_erosion` to find peaks in my spectrum.

I just wondering if there are any other better alternatives?

I have looked at [endolith's project](https://gist.github.com/endolith/250860). But the peaks from it are not spread out evenly in $x$ and $y$ axis.

Comment: @endolith (under that username) posts here, so you might see if we can persuade them to comment / answer.